# Help me identify this connector please!

Tags: vintage

[image: **this is the only connection on a beautiful PE 2005 Turntavle I came across. It spins quietly and I'd love to give it a listen, but I dint know what kind of connection this is. **]
this is the only connection on a vintage turntable I came across. what is it?

Comment: Looks like a [DIN connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector) with one pin missing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like a 180 degrees 5 pin DIN plug.
One of the pins looks like it has broken off, or was never there.
Sockets are readily available.

[image]

I got this picture from here - https://www.wikiwand.com/en/DIN_connector

The website also shows common pin uses in audio.